# I plan on travelling to USA, I have question related to +TAX and +F/S when buying something online (particulary laptop)

Tags: usa, money, shopping, taxes, shipping

So I plan buying a laptop from an online shop when I'm in USA and let's say it costs 1200$ **+TAX or I even saw +F/S** , so please enlighten me about what are those taxes and how is it calculated? And even if I'm not able to go to USA is there any chance of some company shipping electronic products to Europe?

Comment: Where are you planning to be in the US? Sales tax is not assessed by the federal government, but by some combination of state, county, and city. Furthermore, some of these taxes are not assessed on Internet purchases, while others are.

Comment: And how are you planning on paying at the online store? A foreign-issued credit card may not be accepted (high fraud rates).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you would want to buy a laptop from the US for use in Europe? Prices are generally quite similar, the only difference is taxes, but you are liable to pay VAT when importing it into the EU, and will generally not be able to reclaim sales tax, so it ends up being more expensive. Also you'll have a different keyboard (not just the letters, the layout is physically different, look at the Enter key or the left shift key), will get a power adapter with a US plug...

Comment: The laptop prices are way too big here in Europe, for example, most of the new ones have more than 1000euros difference considering US prices and besides that, the specs are even worse here. If I end up not going to US and buying it online (somehow and I don't know how), is there still any chance of fraud? I'd like you to be more accurate about how are taxes calculated and what should I expect (links would help). I use US type keyboard layout and appearance for my whole life and the EU type plugs are cheap, so I have no problems with that. Does my students ID card work for discounts in US? Ty

Comment: Taxes range from zero to close to 9% (NYC is 8.875%) and are added onto the quoted sales price. The tax rate varies depending on where it is shipped (a bit oversimplified) and varies from city to city and state to state. You may have trouble getting a company to accept your order online if your address is temporary (it won't match the billing address on the credit card and fraud is very common on electronics in the US).

Comment: The US (as far as I know anyway) has no convenient facilities for rebating sales tax you pay within the country if you take the item away with you (unlike most other countries) though commercial exporters are exempt. So you could end up paying tax twice if your country charges the VAT.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the acronym F/S.  Can you explain?

Comment: @Michael Seifert the question asks (in part) what F/S is, so I don't suppose the asker of the question will be able to explain.

Comment: Trowing the packaging away and slipping it in your luggage isn't really tax evasion. The moment you unpack the laptop it ceases to be merchandise and just becomes personal property. In most countries you can import that without issues. It's a bit a grey area, but not really illegal.

Comment: @jcron: Some people (me included) find having a standard US keyboard on a laptop an advantage, not a disadvantage. I do a lot of programming, and a standard US keyboard is the best choice for that. On top of that I write in four languages, so would have trouble picking a language specific keyboard anyway. 
One drawback of ordering electronics in the US however is that you end up with lots of useless US power cords. It pains me sometimes throwing all that away.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, my parents live where the sales tax is 9.917% (Sallisaw, OK).

Comment: Another point to consider: if you need support or service, you will have to go back to the to point of sales, which will be difficult.

Comment: I'm personally trying to figure out if I believe this to be on-topic here.... it's an event _while travelling_ yet not part of the travel. It's something a person not from the country being traveled to doesn't understand, but still ... not really seeing the relevance to [travel.se]

Comment: Unless you are using a US issued CC or an online store that happily accepts foreign cards, you will probably find the online store won't accept your card for payment. A verification is usually done against the billing zip code and declined if it doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US tax is calculated at checkout, as there is no general nation wide sales tax (or VAT) as in Europe. Sales tax varies by state, and by town, as it is usually composed of both state and local taxes. 
Prices listed are usually pre-tax prices, which is different from European practice of listing all inclusive prices (which in Europe is mandated by law anyway).

When buying something over the internet Sales Tax will be calculated based on where you live. On top of that Freight/Shipping(F/S) charges may be added.

When ordering something from abroad you will not have to pay the sales tax. But you may end up paying high shipping, and will most certainly be hit with a bill for VAT, import duties, and additional processing and admin fees.

However it is sometimes worthwhile to do this anyway. I have done this myself.

It is often useful to use a local forwarder. That is a service that gives you a mail address in the US, that you can receive parcels on. They will collect the parcel, inform you that something has arrived, and will wait your instructions.

Using such a service has a few advantages:

- Most of them have conveniently located themselves in a place that has
  no sales tax.
- Many On Line vendors in the US offer free shipping
  within the continental US.

Just google "parcel forwarding" to find some. Do a bit of research first before settling on one.

When you tell the forwarder to ship your stuff to your home address he will fill in the necessary customer forms, and quote you how much the shipping will cost. Sometimes they will even give you an estimate of taxes can expect to pay afterwards.

I live in a place with a low VAT rate (7.7%), so the customs bill I get afterwards is usually low. However consider that if you live in a high VAT are (I believe it goes up to 25% in some parts of Europe) you may well end up with a customs bill of >30% of the value of your goods, on top of the forwarding costs. Buying that laptop in the US may end up not be that advantageous after all.